# Составить функции удаления ребра и узла графа

Tags: c++, c

Необходимо было создать список смежности графа и удалить из него определённые ребра (между 0 и 1, 2 и 3, 3 и 8) и узел под номером 5.

Как реализовать функции удаления?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//задание 3

struct adjlistnode //список смежности узла
{
    int dest;
    struct adjlistnode* next;
};
struct adjlist //список смежности
{
    struct adjlistnode* head;
};
struct Graph
{
    int V;
    struct adjlist* array;
};
struct adjlistnode* newadjlistnode(int dest);
struct Graph* creategraph(int V);
void addedge(struct Graph* graph, int src, int dest);
void printgraph(struct Graph* graph);
void deleteedge(struct Graph* graph, int src, int dest);
void deletevertex(struct Graph* graph, int src, int dest);

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");
    int V = 8;
    struct Graph* graph = creategraph(V);
    addedge(graph, 0, 1);
    addedge(graph, 1, 2);
    addedge(graph, 2, 3);
    addedge(graph, 3, 8);
    addedge(graph, 8, 4);
    addedge(graph, 4, 6);
    addedge(graph, 6, 7);
    addedge(graph, 7, 0);
    addedge(graph, 0, 6);
    addedge(graph, 1, 6);
    addedge(graph, 1, 5);
    addedge(graph, 2, 5);
    addedge(graph, 3, 5);
    addedge(graph, 3, 4);
    addedge(graph, 4, 5);
    addedge(graph, 5, 6);
    printgraph(graph);
    return 0;
}

struct adjlistnode* newadjlistnode(int dest)//создание узла нового списка смежности
{
    struct adjlistnode* newnode = new adjlistnode;
    newnode->dest = dest;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    return newnode;
}
struct Graph* creategraph(int V)
{
    struct Graph* graph = new Graph;
    graph->V = V;
    graph->array = new adjlist; // создание массива списков смежности
    int i; //инициализация каждого списка смежности как пустого
    for (i = 0; i < V; ++i)
    {
        graph->array[i].head = NULL;
    }
    return graph;
}
void addedge(struct Graph* graph, int src, int dest)
{
    // + ребро из src в построение. Новый узел + в список смежности. Список src. Узел + в начале
    struct adjlistnode* newnode = newadjlistnode(dest);
    newnode->next = graph->array[src].head;
    graph->array[src].head = newnode;
    newnode = newadjlistnode(src);
    newnode->next = graph->array[dest].head;
    graph->array[dest].head = newnode;
}
void printgraph(struct Graph* graph)
{
    int v;
    for (v = 0; v < graph->V; ++v)
    {
        struct adjlistnode* pCrawl = graph->array[v].head;
        printf("\nСписок смежности вершины %d\n head", v);
        while (pCrawl)
        {
            printf("-> %d", pCrawl->dest);
            pCrawl = pCrawl->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала напишите функцию удаления элемента из однонаправленного списка `struct adjlist`. Затем будет легче.

```
// удаление узла из списка struct adjlist
// возвращает true, если элемент в списке не найден
// возвращает false, если один элемент удалён.
bool  isBADlist_rem  ( struct adjlist & list , int ele ) {
  struct adjlistnode  * jlist = list . head ;
  struct adjlistnode  * jold = nullptr ;
  // цикл с начала списка с запоминанием предыдущего узла
  while ( jlist ) {
    if ( jlist -> dest == ele ) {
      if ( jold )
        // если удаляем середину списка, то исправляем 
        // указатель предыдущего next
        jold -> next = jlist -> next ;
      else
        // если удаляем первый элемент, то исправляем
        // указатель головы списка
        list . head = jlist -> next ;
      delete  jlist ;
      return  false ; }
    jold = jlist ;
    jlist = jlist -> next ;  }
  return  true  ; }
```